# How to fix output not displaying to console in eclipse 2019-03(4.11.0)

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, for-loop, console

I have written a simple for while loop program, the editor window shows no error, however when I run the program the console displays no output.

I've adjusted console preferences, toggling the limit console output and  fixed width console options, I've also tried changing the output to a log file in another location on my system.

```
public class whileLoop {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int x = 10;

while (x < 20)
;
{
System.out.print("Value of X is: " + x);
x++;
System.out.print("\n");
}
}
}
```

Expected results should be a listed as:
Value of x is 10
Value of x is 11
Value of x is 12
Value of x is 13
...

However I have nothings displaying to the screen.

Comment: remove semicolon for while, try my edit code that should work

Comment: @Deadpool Please don't edit out code from questions; what you change very well could be the solution. In most cases, you should instead make your changes in an *answer*.

Comment: ya i agree but how much preferable to answer these type of question? is much worth of it? just i'm still learning @TylerH

Comment: @Deadpool If you think the question is not worth answering, you shouldn't answer in the comments, either. Downvote the question, instead, and, if it's off-topic for one of the given several reasons, vote to close it for that reason as well.

Comment: I agree sir, but my intention is to help him, but not to gain more reputation on easy questions @TylerH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added an extra `;` in your code. Try this:

```py
public class whileLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 10;
        while (x < 20) {
            System.out.print("Value of X is: " + x);
            x++;
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```